# Safari doesn't like certain Backbone routes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, safari

I have a somewhat odd problem. I have the following Backbone routes:

```
  routes:
    "" : "index"
    "foo" : "index"
```

The URI at which I'm working is `/appointments/backbone`. Here's what's weird:

- If I navigate to `/appointments/backbone` in either Chrome or Safari, it works just fine; it's hitting the first route.
- If I navigate to `/appointments/backbone#/#foo` in Chrome it works, but in Safari it doesn't. It converts the URI to `/appointments/backbone/#/%23foo` and I get an error in a `show_view.js`, even though I'm not doing anything remotely related to a show view. Visiting `/appointments/backbone#asdf` or any other gibberish URI produces the same exact error.

I imagine I'm just making some simple mistake. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been wrestling with this for hours, and now, literally two minutes after I posted the question, I've figured out the solution.

Instead of `/appointments/backbone#/#foo`, I need `/appointments/backbone#foo`.